# Selenium - Find out where script was downloaded from

Tags: python, selenium

I have to validate that a web application, when executed in the client browser, is fetching some assets (*.js) from a particular remote server.

Say two options exist: whether it gets the script from server *A* or it gets a copy from server *B*. I need to assert (based on some preconditions) that the script was downloaded from server *A*.

**The question**: Is there a way to inspect source url of loaded javascript using selenium (preferably with python)?

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: My approach so far didn't involve selenium. I am using WireMock to proxy requests made by the browser to the server, but when the assets should come from a different server, that particular request (_if_ it's ever made) doesn't go through the proxy.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc.

Comment: I had never read your second link, a lot of debate over there, right? Do you want my to agree with the selected answer? I feel closer to some of the comments. This is a yes or no question. "Is there a way? Yes, look at this. Is there a way? No, sorry." I did research a lot. I did try different approaches. I've been going around this for a few days now. There's obviously something I don't quite grasp about what selenium is and what it is not. That was the core of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is a possible solution to extract url of javascript libraries from the stackoverflow site.

You should adapt the solution to the site you are working on.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.http://stackoverflow.com/")
link= driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('script')
for i in link:
    print i.get_attribute("src")
```

Example of output:

```
http://rules.quantcount.com/rules-p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc.js
http://edge.quantserve.com/quant.js
http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js
https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=9798373e8e81
```

There are various strategies to locate elements in a page. 
You can use the most appropriate one for your case (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

Comment: Thanks, it's a good start for me. My concern is, still, that this approach can not ensure the scripts where successfuly downloaded. It's inspecting the html and saying "you know what, I see some `script` tags and they have this `src` attribute". I do appreciate the workarround, but I would be interested in doing in selenium the kind of work I can do manually inspecting the network tab on the developers console.

Comment: Got it. You should so investigate https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy and investigate all the requests made by the page loading

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the pointer. I will look into it. So your answer to the original question is that this can't be made solely with selenium, am I right?

Comment: By my experience not only by Selenium. If code inspection it is not enough and you have to monitor all page requests (whenever they are generated), you have to make usage of other libraries with selenium

Comment: Ok, if you'd make that into an answer, I'd be glad to mark it as accepted. Thank you very much for your help and tips.